# How to set MySQL's internal time zone support?

Tags: mysql, database-performance, timezone, rds

Today [MySQL at Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/MySQLatFacebook) posted [the following](https://www.facebook.com/MySQLatFacebook/posts/10152018528871696:0) about MySQL performance:

> Today we found a performance problem in a completely unexpected place - if TIMESTAMP data type is being used and MySQL is configured to use system time zone, it will hit a code in Linux C library which has a global mutex. To add insult to an injury, MySQL's internal time zone support (using mysql.time_zone* tables) is ~30% faster at single thread workload.
>   With 30 client threads MySQL's internal timezone conversion is 30x faster. 
>   The day started with something that looked like a MySQL bug, but apparently it is a MySQL victory. -- domas

How can I determine whether my MySQL instance is using the slower system time zone or whether it's using the faster `mysql.time_zone*` tables? i.e. which MySQL config parameters should I check?

(we actually use Amazon RDS rather than hosting our own database however I don't think that matters other than instead of checking `my.cnf`, I'll need to use the RDS parameter group to check or change config variables. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked article

> Once you load up the files (via [http://dev.mysql.com/.../time-zone-support.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html)), just specify global `time_zone` configuration parameter in `my.cnf`, or change it with `SET GLOBAL ...` - still don't forget to change it in `my.cnf`.
>   Do note, you may want to do that on all the slaves as well, as replication is a bit annoyed by different timezones.

You can determine the global.time_zone setting with

```
mysql> select @@global.time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| SYSTEM             |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for spoon feeding me ;) . Good, using RDS, I get a value of `UTC`. I think this means I'm not using the system time zone which is good (according to the Facebook post).